# Uri accept bad url that start with "www-"

Tags: c#, uri

I'm using this code block:

```
if (!Uri.TryCreate("http://www­-.ageofauti­sm.com/201­0/01/wakef­ields-scie­nce-proven­-valid-aga­in-in-new-­study-that­-replicate­s-findings­.html", UriKind.Absolute, out url) || url.Host == string.Empty)

throw new InvalidUrlException(inputUrl);
```

And the function Uri.TryCreate returns true, instead of false. However that URL is broken because: **"www-" is not valid prefix.**

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www­-.ageofauti­sm.com` is as **valid** as `my-super-server.ageofauti­sm.com`

If this adress **exists** is a different question.

Comment: subdomain can ends with "-"?

Comment: Why not? `-` is a legal character in host names. You may even have `---.mydomain.com`